# setOnItemclicklistner for simplelistitem1 or simplelistitem2

Tags: android

I am using android built in layout android.R.layout.simple_list_item 2. I wanted to perform **onItemclicklistner()** for the items in this layout. I couldn't find the resource id for this layout without which I couldn't find a way to perform the listner function. The examples I have seen so far is

```
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist); // Since I am using built in layout I couldn't figure out the resourse id as in this case.
list.setOnItemClicklistner();
```

So my problem is without knowing the resourse id of the built in layout "simple_list_item 2" how can I create a Listview object. and without having a ListView Object I am unable to access setOnItemClickListner(). Hope I delivered the question in a meaningful way. Thanks

Comment: there can be only two issues , either unsuccessful build or the ID isn't there or you are trying to do this in a fragment

Comment: Layout is [simple_list_item_2.xml](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/simple_list_item_2.xml)

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I tried that too. But that method is deprecated.

Comment: @PavneetSingh Exactly. I didn't know what is the ID of simple_list_item_2 layout that I couldn't proceed furthur. Thats my problem

Comment: if you are using `ListActivity`(seems like yes) then you can use `getListView()`  although it's an cloudy question but the answers are already here to help you

Comment: @PavneetSingh Thanks. This is what I was looking for.

Comment: i am glad that i could help you and i just realize there is a grammar typo in my previous comment `an cloudy ` :P

Answer (score 0):

```
use setonItemClickListner(); 

listview.setOnItemClickListner(new OnItemClick(){});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use setOnItemClickListener() instead of setOnClickListener()

Comment: Sorry guys. Thats a typo.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform clicks on items in the `ListView`, try using `OnItemClickListener` in place of `OnClickListener`. The `OnItemClickListener` can be set on the `ListView` as shown below.

```
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            // Perform the required tasks here
        }
    });
```

Comment: But my doubt is different. I am unable to create Listview object as I am using android.R.layout.simple_list_item 2.

Comment: @NishantJ - You're using the `android.R.layout.simple_list_item2` as the layout for each list item inside the `ListView`. But, you mush have added the ListView widget somewhere inside your Activity's layout xml file. In that xml code, there should be an `ID` tag for the `ListView` widget. Use that `ID` to instantiate the `ListView` object.

Comment: @NishantJ - I hope this time I have understood your question correctly. In case, you don't understand my above comment or have any more doubts, please feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

for list item click u should set  onItemClickListener like below

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position,
        long id) {


}
});
```

also you can set onItemClickListener Interface to your Activity and override method in activity